# How to prevent jest to show fail test details on summary

Tags: jestjs

When I run my tests with jest and some of them fails for each item failed I get a list like this:

```
 FAIL  src/app/models/item.model.spec.ts
  ● Item› #getItem › do stuff

    expect(received).toBeFalsy()

    Received: true

      293 |
      294 |     test('do stuff', () => {
    > 295 |       expect(true).toBeFalsy();
          |                    ^
      296 |     });
      297 |   });
      298 | });

      at src/app/models/item.model.spec.ts:295:20
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:26)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:129:39)
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390:52)
      at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:150:43)
      at Object.testBody.length (node_modules/jest-preset-angular/zone-patch/index.js:52:27)
```

which is the same info that I get above when the test first failed. In the case when a suite is really big and something breaks all their tests (or in more than one file) is really impossible to read that list because the details are always between the `FAIL` title and test names.

Is there a way to do jest to print a compact Failed Tests summary like this?

```
FAIL  src/app/models/item.model.spec.ts
  ● Item› #getItem › do stuff
  ● Item› #getItem › do another Stuff
FAIL  src/app/models/loader.model.spec.ts
  ● Loader> #loadSomething › be cool
  ● Loader› #loadAnything › be cooler
```

So if I want to read the fail details I can just scroll up or filter the failed test in my next run.